# Change color of ListView Selected Item and also change different color to non selected Items

Tags: android, android-listview

`Listview` Items have default color Black. Now, when user clicks on any Item, I want to change its color as Gray so remaining Items color will be Black. If user again clicks on another item then that Item's color should become Gray and remaining items of black color.

I know for one time changing color but after clicking on another item, I don't know how to change all remaining Items color.

Comment: u only want to change color on press on button or just click then permanent change until unless other one will not be select

Comment: In your custom adaptor class change the background of the listview item layout colour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try following code in your onItemClickListener

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
                    View item = listview.getChildAt(i);
                    if (item != null) {
                        item.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                    }
                }
                arg1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            }
        });
```

Comment: thank you. It has solved my problem. I tried same code before but I din't find for item View that's why It was not working.

Answer (score 0):

In your customAdater class

```
  convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {

         TextViewName.setTextColor(getApplication().getResources()
                    .getColor(R.color.YOUR_COLOR));

    }

   });
```